# How Can I access function calculateRoute from outside of the component?

Tags: reactjs

and I have a component with Google Maps. I have a const isLoaded which loads the maps basically. In order to use some sort of commands such as " new google.maps.DirectionsService() " I need that isLoaded method. And I wrote a menthod inside my Component, but I have to use it outside of the component.

```
import { DirectionsRenderer, GoogleMap, Marker, Polyline, useJsApiLoader } from '@react-google-maps/api'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { MAPS_API_KEY } from '../../constants/keys'
import { libraries } from '../../constants/constants'
import { LoadingOpen } from '../../constants/functions'




const Map = ({type, items, navigate}) => {
    const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: 29.585398049582135, lng: -12.071279993875516 })
    const [map, setMap] = useState(/** @type google.maps.Map */(null))

    const {isLoaded} = useJsApiLoader({
      googleMapsApiKey: MAPS_API_KEY,
      libraries: libraries
    })

    const calculateRoute = async (item) => {
      let stops = [];
      if (item.waypoints[0].stops.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < item.waypoints[0].stops.length; i++) {
          stops.push(item.waypoints[0].stops[i].stoplocation)
        }
      }
    
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      
      const results = await directionsService.route({
        origin: item.waypoints[0].startdirection,
        destination: item.waypoints[0].enddirection,
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        waypoints: stops
    
      });
    
      return results;
    }
    if (!isLoaded) {
        return (
            <>
                {LoadingOpen()}
            </>
        )
    }

  return <GoogleMap
  center={center}
  zoom={3}
  options={{
    draggableCursor: 'default',     
  }}
  onLoad={(map) => setMap(map)}
  mapContainerStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}

>
   {type === 'home' ? (
    <>
     {items.travels.length > 0 && (
    <>
      {
     
        items.travels.map((element, i) => {
       
          if (element.type === 'travellocation') {
          
            return <div onClick={() => navigate(`/travel?id=${element.item._id}`)}><DirectionsRenderer onClick={() => navigate(`/travel?id=${element.item._id}`)} options={{preserveViewport: true,polylineOptions:{strokeColor:'blue', strokeWeight:2},  markerOptions:{icon:`http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png`}}} directions={element.item} /></div>
          } else if (element.type === 'travelpin') {
            let wps = element.item.waypoints;
            let coords = [];
            wps.forEach((wp) => {
              wp.coords.forEach((coord) => {
                coords.push(coord)
              })
            })
            return (
              <>
               <Marker position={coords[0]} icon={`http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png`}/>
              <Marker position={coords[coords.length -1]} icon={`http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png`} />
              <Polyline onClick={() => navigate(`/travel?id=${element.item._id}`)} path={coords} options={{ geodesic: true, strokeOpacity: 1, strokeWeight: 2, strokeColor: 'blue', draggable: false, editable: false, clickable: true }} />
              </>
            )
          } else if (element.type === 'location') {

            return <Marker onClick={() => navigate(`/location?id=${element.item._id}`)} key={i} position={element.item.locationCoords} icon={`http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png`} />
          }
        })
      }
    </>
  )}
    </>
   ) : null
   
   }
 
</GoogleMap>

}

export default Map
```

So this is the component I've created and on another Page, another File, I have to call that calculateRoute so I can obtain some data. But if I wanna do that I get this.

[image]

I cannot call that method outside of the component. I tried to put it somewhere else, but it needs the isLoaded method in order to work. I was looking online, but I couldn't understand the syntax so that's why I am here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to call things like `new google.maps.DirectionsService()` but you can't until `isLoaded` is true?

You just need to wait until `isLoaded` is true before calling `calculateRoute`, and it should work fine.

```js
if (isLoaded) {
    calculateRoute(item);
}
```

However, if you are trying to use this inside of another component then you might need to be using the `useEffect` hook ([docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect)) instead. Something like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   if (isLoaded) {
       calculateRoute(item);
   }
}, [isLoaded]);
```

With the above call to `useEffect`, it will only call the `calculateRoute` function when `isLoaded` is true. If `isLoaded` changes (i.e. becomes true) then `useEffect` will re-trigger and it will be called.

Comment: I need to be able to call it from an external file. So I have the page Dashboard.jsx let's say and in that page I have the state for Dashboard, the data coming from the backend. And for some of the data I want to apply the calculateRoute method which is in the Map.jsx Component. I keep it there because there is where isLoaded method is located.

Comment: What I'd probably recommend for this is that you restructure things a bit. Generally in react you want to avoid passing data between peer components like what you are trying to do. Instead, the component with `isLoading` should be a parent that provides that data down to it's children. If you really don't want to do that, you could try looking at creating a [provider](https://mortenbarklund.com/blog/react-architecture-provider-pattern/), particularly if you plan to use the data in multiple other parts of the app.